# Contracting homotopies of a projective resolution of $k[x]/(f)$

Tags: polynomials, homological-algebra

This issue began as an attempt to understand the projective resolution of $R = k[x]/(x^{n+1})$ that appears in Weibel (Exercise 9.1.4)

$$\cdots\to R^e \xrightarrow{u}  R^e \xrightarrow{v} R^e \xrightarrow{u} R^e \xrightarrow{\mu} R \to 0$$

where $u = x\otimes 1 - 1\otimes x$, $v = \sum_{i=0}^n x^{n-i}\otimes x^i$ and $\mu$ is multiplication. I found [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266984855_Cyclic_homology_of_algebras_with_one_generator) paper that constructs a projective resolution for the more general ring $A = k[x]/(f)$ where $f$ is a degree $n$ monic polynomial

I was hoping to make use of the contracting homotopies that appear in this paper and apply them to the resolution for $R$ to show that it is in fact a resolution, but I'm struggling to make sense of them, so I'll just define them and go through what I understand so far.

There are three maps that make up the contracting homotopies, $s_0:A\to A^e$, $s_1:A^e\to A^e$ and $s_2:A^e\to A^e$, defined as

$$s_0(P)= 1\otimes P,\quad s_1(P\otimes 1) = \frac{T(P)}{T(x)}, \quad s_2(P\otimes 1) = \bar{Px}\otimes 1$$

where $P$ is a polynomial in $A$ and $T(P) = 1\otimes P - P\otimes 1$. The resolution, and its contracting homotopies is

$$
\cdots \substack{\xrightarrow{v}\\[-1em] \xleftarrow[s_2]{}\\[-1em]} A^e \substack{\xrightarrow{u}\\[-1em] \xleftarrow[s_1]{}\\[-1em] } A^e \substack{\xrightarrow{v}\\[-1em] \xleftarrow[s_2]{}\\[-1em] } A^e
\substack{\xrightarrow{u}\\[-1em] \xleftarrow[s_1]{}\\[-1em] } A^e
\substack{\xrightarrow{\mu}\\[-1em] \xleftarrow[s_0]{}\\[-1em] } A \to 0
$$

where $u(a\otimes b) = (a\otimes b)T(x)$ and $v(a\otimes b) = (a\otimes b)\frac{T(f)}{T(x)}$. To be clear, the arrows on the bottom read $s_2$, $s_1$, $s_2$, $s_1$, $s_0$ and the arrows on top read $v$, $u$, $v$, $u$, $\mu$, from left to right. I had issues formatting the arrows so apologies for that.

If I've understood things correctly, I think that $\frac{T(P)}{T(x)}$ can be written

$$\frac{T(P)}{T(x)} = \sum_{i=0}^np_i\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}x^j\otimes x^{i-j-1}$$

and then $s_1(P\otimes 1) = \sum_{i=0}^np_i\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}x^j\otimes x^{i-j-1}$ and $v(a\otimes b)$ can be written in a similar way. Then of course the aim is to show that

$$s_1u + vs_2 = \mbox{id}, \quad s_2v + us_1 = \mbox{id}, \quad s_0\mu + us_1 = \mbox{id}, \quad \mu s_0 = \mbox{id} $$

Demonstrating $\mu s_0 = \mbox{id}$ is easy enough, so I've had no issues there.

That's all I understand so far, so on to my questions.
There are a few things that I don't understand about this:

1. Why are $s_1$ and $s_2$ only defined on $P\otimes 1$? It's not obvious to me that $P\otimes 1$ generates $A^e$, so I'm not sure why it's only necessary to know how $s_1$ and $s_2$ act on these elements (**Edit: This question has now been answered in the comments**).
2. What exactly does $\bar{Px}$ mean? From the notation in the paper my thinking is that $P\in A$ is considered as an element of $k[x]$ and then $\bar{Px}$ is $(Px)\mbox{ mod}f$ as it were? However, I'm not sure, so any clarification would be appreciated.
3. (**Edit: Re a point made in the comments: All the calculations done in this question are done using the definitions from the paper. "My $u$" that the comment refers to I think is the $u$ I define at the beginning of this post, but that $u$ is never actually used, it's only present because it's the definition given in Weibel, which was the motivating problem that lead to me asking this question**) Ignoring for the moment my issue with the definition of $s_1$, when I calculate $(s_0\mu + us_1)(P\otimes 1)$ I get
   \begin{align}
   (s_0\mu + us_1)(P\otimes 1) & = s_0(\mu(P\otimes 1)) + u(s_1(P\otimes 1))\\
                               & = 1\otimes P + \frac{T(P)}{T(x)}T(x) \\
                               & = 1\otimes P + 1\otimes P - P\otimes 1\\
                               & = 2(1\otimes P) - P\otimes 1
   \end{align}which, unless I'm missing some obvious relation in $A^e$, is not equal to $P\otimes 1$. I've gone over this countless times looking for a mistake but I can't find one. Assuming I've not made a mistake, this is solved by putting a minus sign in front of $\frac{T(P)}{T(x)}$ in the definition of $s_1$. But I'm wary of declaring that there is a typo in the paper, so I come to you for a second opinion. Have I made a mistake somewhere? Or is this a typo in the paper?

I've made a tentative attempt at calculating the other two relations but they've proven to be a bit more complicated and not fully understanding the definition of $s_2$ doesn't help either, so I've not made much progress there. The authors of the paper assure the reader that the relations can be shown by direct calculation, so I can only assume that it's possible.
In any case, any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: they are defined on $P\otimes 1$ as they are defined to be "right A-maps" i.e. homomorphisms of right $A$-modules. The sign error is because their $T(x)$ has the opposite sign to your $u$.

Comment: @MatthewTowers So if I understand you, if the maps are homomorphisms of right $A$-modules, then we can write $s_1(P_1\otimes P_2) = s_1((P_1\otimes 1)P_2) =s_1(P_1\otimes 1)P_2$? 

With the sign error, I never actually use that first $u$ in any calculations, I included it as context. All calculations were done using the definitions that appear in the paper. So in question 3 $u$ is multiplication by $T(x)=1\otimes x - x\otimes 1$, and *not* multiplication by $x\otimes 1 - 1\otimes x$, so I'm fairly certain that the sign is the right way around. Or have I misunderstood your comment?